# Sql запрос UPDATE replace где ошибка?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, которая хранит в себе id и param.

Параметры хранятся в виде:

```
[p1=>1][p2=>2][p3=>3]...
```

Задача обновить в таблице t все значения параметра р1.

Делаю запрос:

```
UPDATE t SET param = replace(param,'\[p1=>\w+[a-zA-Z0-9_]\]', '[p1=>333]')
```

Но запрос не срабатывает.

В чём ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вроде так создаётся запрос, если не ошибаюсь

    UPDATE t SET param1 = "\[p1=>\w+[a-zA-Z0-9_]\]", param2 = "[p1=>333]" WHERE id = 1

Ещё вот [справка ][1]

  [1]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL)

Comment: НЕТ вы не правильно поняли! [p1=>1][p2=>2][p3=>3] это одна ячейка в строке а в таблице таких строк много=))

Comment: @Флекс, где-то я такое уже видел, тип столбца должен быть 'SET'.
Тогда запрос выглядит как-то так:

    UPDATE t SET param = REPLACE(param, '[p1=>\w+[a-zA-Z0-9_]]', '[p1=>333]') WHERE id = 1

или так:

    UPDATE t SET param = REPLACE(param, '[p1=>\w+[a-zA-Z0-9_]]', '[p1=>333]') WHERE param LIKE %'[p1=>\w+[a-zA-Z0-9_]]'%

Comment: WHERE id = 1 тут вообще ни при чём нужно искать по всей таблице, мне кажется, просто mysql регулярку не понимает, а где, я не знаю. (

Comment: @Флекс, я с таким не сталкивался, попробуйте регулярку в кавычки поставить

Comment: Ставил уже не помогает. )     
Если, например, делать вот так:

    UPDATE  t SET  param = replace(params,'[p1=>1]','[p1=>333]')

Все работает но регулярку '[p1=>\w+[a-zA-Z0-9_]]' не кушает(( Привередливый собака=))

Comment: Ничего не могу найти, пока накопал http://chesser.ru/blog/how_to_regexp_replace_text_field_in_mysql/

Answer (score 1):

> где ошибка?

Это один из тех вопросов, ответ на который очевиден и очень прост: в архитектуре БД.

Такое часто случается, когда с базой данных начинают работать люди, которые до того с программированием не сталкивались, и пытаются перетащить в мир *реляционных* баз данных привычную им бумажную технологию.

Разумеется, вот этот вот - не побоюсь этого слова - чудовищный формат, `[p1=>1][p2=>2][p3=>3]` должен быть немедленно нормализован, и вместо единственного поля под него долна быть отдана целая таблица вида

```
id | p  | value
12 | p1 | 1
12 | p2 | 2
12 | p3 | 3
```

где id - это уникальный идентификатор из старой таблицы с чудовищным полем.

как можно себе представить, редактирование параметров в такой таблице не представляет ни малейшей трудности.

Тем более, что REPLACE все равно не поддерживает регулярки, уж не знаю, откуда эта идея изначально у автора взялась.